# Received Java was started but returned exit code=13 error when starting STS on 64-bit machine

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to open Spring Tool Suite, but I am getting the following error:

[image: error]

I'm using Windows 7 and have 64-bit.

I have **jre1.8.0_181** in *Program Files (x86)*.

And I have **jdk1.8.0_151** in *Program Files*.

When I run java -version, I get:

[image: cmd]

STS was working fine yesterday, but not today. What could be causing this issue, as I haven't changed any configuration?

How do I find out if my java versions are 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Haven't worked with STS, but it seems to be based on eclipse, so you should have an eclipse.ini file there somewhere. In it, you should set the "-vm" part to point to the VM you wish it to use. See: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example

Comment: Hi @YoavGur I've searched for _eclipse.ini_ in the JRE and JDK, but it doesn't appear to be in either

Comment: You should search for it where STS is installed.

Comment: @YoavGur OK, so I've found the _STS.ini_ file. Here is what it contains: 
`-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1200m`

Comment: Did you try to add "-vm" with the path to the JRE you want to use?

Comment: @YoavGur I've updated it to the following `-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1200m` The jre is stored in C/ProgramFiles/Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by adding the following code to the *STS.ini* file:

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\javaw.exe
```